# System.LimitException: reports:Too many query rows: 50001

Tags: apex, reporting, reports-api

I am getting this error when I try to run report in apex like this :
Reports.ReportResults reportResults = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, false);

Because, the report has more than 50,000 rows. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: This might help you  ---- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984349/limitexception-too-many-query-rows-50001-from-with-count-aggregate-function

Answer (score 1):

As you've indicated, the report you are trying to run has more than 50000 rows. You need to limit the report to less than 50000 rows.

You have a couple of options:

1. Navigate to the report and add a filter to reduce the rows returned (similar to this question: [How to filter Report by row limit in Report API?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132405/how-to-filter-report-by-row-limit-in-report-api))
2. Dynamically add a filter to the report using the reporting api (similar to this Salesforce help doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_filter_reportdata.htm)